# I get the following error while running an npm start. I have tried rebuilding the code all over but I still get it

Tags: reactjs, npm

I was trying to bring up my local environment. It does open a chrome window on npm start but the site crashes as soon as it is up. Following is the error that I get:

```
internal/buffer.js:940class FastBuffer extends Uint8Array {}
^

RangeError: Invalid typed array length: -4095
    at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
    at new FastBuffer (internal/buffer.js:940:1)
    at Handle.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:181:19)
    at Stream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\afzah\work\FEC\workdir\sub_module\node_modules\handle-thing\lib\handle.js:120:12)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (C:\Users\afzah\work\FEC\workdir\sub_module\node_modules\spdy-transport\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:1010:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! positions-ts@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the positions-ts@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-03T10_15_15_669Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you using the native Buffer API somewhere on the App initialization?

Comment: can you post some code with minimum reproducable issue

Comment: I had done no change in code. I upgraded the node version though. Seems like the given class is not supported in the versions later than 10.15.3